# Eclipse unable to connect to internet when using a VPN

Tags: eclipse, vpn

Eclipse is unable to connect to the internet when I am using a VPN.

The VPN I am using is: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/

I have no issues when I try browsing the web using the VPN.

If I try to do something like access the Eclipse Marketplace I get an error saying connection fails and it suggests I should check my internet connection and retry.

I have tried restarting eclipse many times.  I have tried changing my network connection preferences in eclipse (Direct, Manual, Native).

I don't really understand why connecting to a VPN should have any effect on eclipse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720780/cannot-open-eclipse-marketplace-cannot-install-remote-marketplace-locations-can)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you have not set proxy (and login credentials) in the eclipse.